# Sort Array of objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

Currently I am working on a contact manager project where I have a contactMgr class, and a contact class within the contactMgr class that stores a contacts info.

To start out the program, I create a contactMgr array with 20 indices. Then, when I create a contact, that includes name, email and phone number, I then store it in the contactMgr array. All of the fields for the contact object are stored as Strings.

How can I sort the contact objects in the contactMgr array alphabetically by name?

Comment: Let `ContractMgr` implement [`Comparable<ContractMgr>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), then call [`Array.sort(yourContractMgrArray)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) for this:

```
ContactMgr[] contacts = ...;
Arrays.sort(contacts, (ContactMgr left, ContactMgr right)
    -> left.getName().compareTo(right.getName())
);
```

Or if the ContactMgr already implements `Comparable` interface and it works as comparing the names, you can call `Arrays.sort(contact)` with default comparator.

Comment: So I tried implementing the Comparable interface with the Contact class, but it won't let me pass in Contact as an argument to Arrays.sort.